# Not getting correct sequence of numbers

Tags: c#, loops, pagination

I'm writing a pagination feature in one of our oracle sql calls which use the `OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY` feature and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to call this without using duplicate numbers.

Currently I'm doing something like this on the C# side where `_currOffset` is `x` and `_nextOffset` is `y`.

```
private int _currOffset = 0;
private int _maxFetchCount = 499;
private int _maxOffset = 2020;
private int _nextOffset = 0;

while(_currOffset < _maxOffset) {
    // If we are going to go over _maxOffset, just take the difference
    _nextOffset = (_currOffset + _maxFetchCount > _maxOffset) ? _maxOffset - _currOffset : _maxFetchCount;

    // Call Database using _currOffset and _nextOffset
    // .... OFFSET _currOffset ROWS FETCH NEXT _nextOffset ROWS ONLY

    _currOffset += _nextOffset + 1;
}
```

This will work fine for the two iterations since `_currOffset` will be `0` and `_nextOffset` would be `499` the first time around and `_currOffset` is `500` and `_nextOffset` is still `499` the second iteration.

For the third iteration `_currOffset` is now `501` which is **wrong**. It should remain `1 + <the last offset I ended with>`.

I basically want to query in chunks without repeating an offset.

1. Query from `0` to `499`
2. Query from `500` to `999`
3. Query from `1000` to `1499`
4. Query from `1500` to `1999`
5. Query from `1999` to `2020` (The if condition will set `_nextOffset` to `21` in this case)

How do I change my assignments of variables to handle this? I can't just remove `_currOffset += _nextOffset + 1` since I would query the same offset twice within my sql query. (I would end with `499` for the first iteration, and begin with `499` for the second iteration when I want to begin with `500` for the second iteration)

Comment: Create a mental model of what you **expect** the code to do. Then, start debugging. Step through it, line by line. Before each line executes, ask yourself 'what do I expect this line of code to do?'. Then run it. Did it do that? If it didn't then there is your bug.

Comment: Your maxFetchCount is 500, but your first chunk (0-500) is 501 items.

Comment: @hatchet You are right, I want to go in chunks of `500` and wasn't accounting for `0`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things can be changed that should get you the values you're looking for:

- The `while` condition runs as long as the `start` value is `<=` the last item index.
- When we can calculate the page `size` we add `1` to the `true` condition (when `start + maxSize > lastItem`) in order to include the first item in the size (for example, `5 - 1` is `4`, but the number of items from `1` to `5` is actually `5`), so `size` becomes `lastItem - start + 1`.
- When we display (or set a variable to) the last item index, it's calculated as `start + size - 1`. For example, if we have a size of `2` and a starting item of `5`, then the last item is `6` (`5` + `2` - `1`)
- Finally, we just add `size` to our `start` value at the end of the loop

---

**Code Sample**

```
private static void Main()
{
    var start = 0;
    var maxSize = 500;

    // Note that this represents the last item's *index*
    // There are actually 2021 total items, since the first item is at index '0'
    var lastItem = 2020;  

    while (start <= lastItem)
    {
        int size = start + maxSize > lastItem 
            ? lastItem - start + 1
            : maxSize;

        Console.WriteLine($"Query from {start} to {start + size - 1} ({size} items)");

        start += size;
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Note that I renamed your variables so the code was more condensed. They map out like:

- `_currOffset = start`
- `_maxFetchCount = maxSize`
- `_maxOffset = lastItem`
- `_nextOffset = size`

---

**Output**

[image]